# File Permissions inside mounted directories

Tags: linux, mount

i currently have a problem with permissions inside a mounted folder.
I mounted a folder from one server with cifs to another and everything works fine.(I also use gocryptfs)
The problem is that inside the folder every file has the same permissions (eg. 770) and the same owner. I can't change it with chmod or chown. It doesm not return an error but the permissions also don't change. I know i can change the user with the uid and gid setting but this results in another user for every file.

What i want is to be able to freely change user and file permissions like normal without being restricted to one.

I added the two following lines to /etc/fstab

```
"{server}" /_z_home_da/gitlab_ext_crypt cifs credentials=/etc/gitlab/.hetzner_storage_box_credentials,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,iocharset=utf8,rw,nofail,_netdev  0 0

/_z_home_da/gitlab_ext_crypt /_z_home_da/datar_20231015939_ferchau.cloud/app_gitl_32338_d/data/repositories fuse./usr/bin/gocryptfs rw,nofail,auto,x-systemd.idle-timeout=10,x-systemd.automount,nonempty,allow_other,quiet,passfile=/etc/gitlab/.hetzner_storage_box_gocryptfs 0 0
```

What are the right settings to achieve my goal?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: thoroughly possible that your cryptographic overlay filesystem (never heard of gocryptfs!) doesn't support it, or that the server you're using is not allowing the user you're authenticating as to set any other ownership or permissions.

Comment: Note that I find it very questionable what you're doing there: This smells like you're trying to use a cloud CIFS storage provider as backend to share a git repository: that's kind of … let's say, it's original. To share access to git repositories, use git. That's what git and gitlab are for. If you want to use external storage for your git data, you don't need different users. And: CIFS wouldn't be the protocol of choice for that. It really makes more sense to keep the roundtrips between your git backend (gitlab) and its storage short. If you want to store gitlab data in an encrypted cloud …

Comment: … setup, then CIFS is simply the wrong choice; go for gitlab's [object storage backend](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html), which supports encrypted storage to begin with.

Comment: For repo storage, since you're already paying hetzner anyways, pull up a VM with what Hetzner calls "Volume" attached with enough space (you can later resize if you need, don't oversize just yet) that runs [gitaly](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/gitaly/index.html) on it – the question is whether you wouldn't want the same server to also run the rest of your gitlab instance.

Comment: Yeah i just want to store gitlab data encrypted on an other server because the storage is cheaper on a storage server. The problem is that gitlab wants to change the owner and permission of the files and directories. When it tries to do it nothing changes and then it throws errors. Ill look into your suggestions thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a guess because I don't completely understand your question - or what you are trying to accomplish. That said:

Using CIFS to mount a file system in Linux will never give you the ability to *"freely change user and file permissions like normal"*. This is because FAT-based filesystems do not include the metadata that allows you to `chown` or `chmod` as you *"normally do"* in filesystems such as `ext4`.

Instead, the filesystems (typically FAT; FAT16, FAT32, exFAT) that are mounted using CIFS in Linux assign ownership and permissions on a ***"per mount"*** basis using `uid`, `gid`, `umask`, `dmask` and `fmask`. That means that every file and directory in that mounted filesystem all share the same values of `uid`, `gid`, `umask`, `dmask` and `fmask`.

I hope this helps clear things up. If not, post a comment. If this doesn't answer your question **at all**, please let me know, and I'll delete it.

Comment: NTFS mounts also have the same metadata issues. I still wrestle with decades of legacy Windows partitions.

Comment: Ok thanks. That clears it out for me. Then i have to find an other way.

Comment: @Lemior: Sorry if this answer disappoints you, and as you said there **are** alternatives.  But please [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) before you move on.